# Copy Site option -- Manage Content and Structure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-permissions

We are using 2016 On Prem

I would like my admin users to be able to copy sub site via Conent And Structure

However they do not see copy option, they only see Move. As a site collection admin i can see copy

Does anyone know what is the minimum permission required for the copy option to be available

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what I believe they need the contribute permissions on the site collection level and subsites.

specifically make sure they have this:

- "Manage Permissions"
- "Manage Web Site"
- "Add and Customize Pages"

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I can confirm the user has three permissions listed above, however they only see Move and not the copy option as we hope them to

Comment: can you give them full control

Comment: Sure do you mean site collection admin or did you mean another permission level/permission

Comment: Add into site collection admins.

Comment: That works butiwas hoping to avoid doing that if possible

Comment: make sure they have full control on subsite, if they dont then they cant move that subsite....i will give them full control and gradually lower them to see where it fix

Answer (score 0):

I tested with many custom permission levels. Even Full control does not provide the permission to copy site. The account needs to be the site collection admin to copy sites.

Comment: Thank you Jerry and Waqas. Site collection is what we need. Appreciate your quick responses